# Python type hints: what should I use for a variable that can be any iterable?

Tags: python, type-hinting

Consider the function:

```
def mysum(x)->int:
    s = 0
    for i in x:
        s += i
    return s
```

The argument `x` can be `list[int]` or `set[int]`, it can also be `d.keys()` where d is a dict, it can be `range(10)`, as well as any other iterable, where the item is of type int. What is the correct type-hint for `x`?

My python is 3.10+.

Comment: Terminology nitpick: a "sequence" has a specific meaning in Python. All sequences are iterable. Tuples, lists, strings are sequences. A set is not a sequence. I think you just mean "iterable"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`typing.Iterable`](https://docs.python.org/library/typing.html#typing.Iterable):

```
from typing import Iterable

def mysum(x: Iterable[int]) -> int:
    s = 0
    for i in x:
        s += i
    return s
```

---

Edit: `typing.Iterable` is an alias for [`collections.abc.Iterable`](https://docs.python.org/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Iterable), so you should use that instead, as suggested in the comments.

Comment: That's deprecated. Use `collections.abc.Iterable` instead.

Comment: @wjandrea `typing.Iterable` is an alias for `collections.abc.Iterable`. What would be the difference?

Comment: That it's deprecated, that's it. I.e., it'll be removed in some future version of Python.

Comment: @wjandrea The docs say the removal of aliases is as of yet undecided. It's a fair point though, thanks for raising it.